# Como inverter (espelhar/flip) uma imagem

Tags: css, imagem, image

Bom, eu preciso de inverter uma imagem de preferência se possível com CSS. Não sei se e possível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria meter a seta a apontar para a esquerda. Obrigado

Answer (score 19, accepted):

É possível sim, com a propriedade [`tansform: scaleX(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleX) fazes isso facilmente:

```css
img {
  width: 260px;
}
#esquerda {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<img id="direita" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Elb.png">
<img id="esquerda" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Elb.png">
```

Comment: Faz uma com rotate tambem (e bota uma observação para que no caso da seta, **por acaso**, como é simétrica, dá certo) :P

Answer (score 5):

Dentro do atributo transform, existem também as funções **rotate(), rotateX(), rotateY(), rotate3d() e rotateZ()**, todas elas trabalham com a unidade *deg* ou em português graus, os valores básicos podem ser qualquer um de 0 a 360*.

Para o seu caso, vc faria uma rotação no eixo Y de 180º, ficando algo assim.

```
.refletir-esquerda{
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Observações:

1. os valores atributos as rotações podem ser qualquer número, até mesmo os negativos, esse valores fazer sentido quando você quer animar o objeto, por exemplo o número 720 indica que houve duas rotações completas.
2. valores negativo interfere na direção da rotação.

mais sobre as funções do transform em [mozilla transform function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function)

Answer (score -2):

Rapaz, o que você está tentando fazer se chama **espelhamento de imagem**.

O CSS possui esse recurso, como o Miguel bem falou. Mas existem diversos editores de imagens por aí que fazem o espelhamento de imagens e que eu, particularmente, opto por usar.

Se tu quiser algo mais básico e compreensível, usa o **Photoscape**. Ele é de graça e bem prático e fácil de usar.

Agora, se tu quiser algo mais profissional que usa não só coisas básicas como máscaras, efeitos e etc., sugiro o **Corel Draw** ou o próprio **Adobe Photoshop**.

Mas como é só um espelhamento de imagem que tu precisa, usa comandos do CSS mesmo.

Comment: Só um detalhe, tu tinha falado em "inverter imagem". Se fosse inversão de imagem mesmo que tu queria, a área em braco ficaria preto e vice-versa.

Answer (score -4):

Até mesmo o Paint possui esse recurso. Ele é bem básico.
Eu uso o Corel Draw mesmo. 
Mas como a maioria da galera já citou existem vários programas capazes, uns mais robustos e como disse, até mesmo o velho Paint rs.
Um abraço